# JAX-WS service with HTTP-GET with status 200

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, http-get

i have the following requirement.
Have to make a SOAP web service( contract first) over HTTP with POST command. However,
while the endpoint operates with POST it needs to answer on empty GET command with 200.
This requirment is fixed and cannot be changed( the logic is that GET will point if 
the server is online)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Creating a JAX-RS resource class that delegates to the JAX-WS service might work.

Comment: You can try to add servlet filter above your jax-ws service that answers GET's and forwards POST's to JAX-WS implementtion

Comment: @Konstantin V. Salikhov: this works, thanks